# vhdl asynchronous assignment in for loop

Tags: for-loop, asynchronous, variable-assignment, vhdl

I am doing something like this:

```
x        : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);

signal x_d: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

type inp_concat_array is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); 
signal inp_concat : inp_concat_array;

process (clk, reset)

begin

   if (rising_edge(clk)) then 

        if (reset = '1') then

            for i in 0 to 15 loop

                x_d(i) <= '0';  

            end loop;

        else 

            for i in 0 to 15 loop

                x_d(i) <= x(i); 

            end loop;

        end if;

   end if;


end process;



for j in 0 to 15 loop

    inp_concat(j) <= x(j) & x_d(j);

end loop;
```

Xilinx ISE 14.2 gives following errors

Syntax error near "for"
Syntax error near "loop"

Can i use asynchronous assignments in FOR loop?

Answer (score 2):

The concurrent `for` loop must be made with a `generate` statement like:

```
inp_concat_loop : for j in 0 to 15 generate
  inp_concat(j) <= x(j) & x_d(j);
end generate;
```

or in a process as described in David Koontzs answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing an entire design description answering your question could be a bit risky.  You present us with a code fragment and no line numbers for the syntax error.  The code fragment contains three for loops.

Now if this fragment represents a continuous segment extracted from a design unit (an architecture) it would appear that you are trying to use a loop statement (the for loop, a sequential statement appropriate for a process or subprogram) in a place appropriate for a concurrent statement (the architecture body).

Providing missing bits for something that might analyze:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity asyn is
    port (
         x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
         clk:    in std_logic;
         reset:  in std_logic
     );
 end entity;

architecture foo of asyn is
signal x_d: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

    type inp_concat_array is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal inp_concat : inp_concat_array;

begin 
    process (clk, reset)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            if (reset = '1') then
                for i in 0 to 15 loop
                    x_d(i) <= '0';  
                end loop;
            else 
                for i in 0 to 15 loop
                    x_d(i) <= x(i); 
                end loop;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    for j in 0 to 15 loop
        inp_concat(j) <= x(j) & x_d(j);
    end loop; 

end architecture;
```

And using a different tool yields:

```
ghdl -a async.vhdl
async.vhdl:32:5: a generate statement must have a label
async.vhdl:32:22: 'generate' is expected instead of 'loop'
```

In a place appropriate for a concurrent statement in an architecture body the only statement that can have a for keyword is a generate statement, which requires a label.

There is no requirement in VHDL to look ahead to disambiguate syntax errors (which is why you have a vague error message).

A different tool provides a bit better illustration:

```
nvc -a async.vhdl
** Error: syntax error, unexpected for, expecting process
    File async.vhdl, Line 32
        for j in 0 to 15 loop
        ^^^
```

So if you put the for loop in a process instead it just might analyze:

```
NEW_PROCESS:
    process (x,x_d)
    begin
        for j in 0 to 15 loop
            inp_concat(j) <= x(j) & x_d(j);
        end loop; 
    end process;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a suggestion for a simpler, neater solution. Simulation results follow.

```
-----------------------------------------------
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-----------------------------------------------
entity test is
  port (
    clk, reset: in std_logic;
    x: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    --test signals:
    test: out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    test_index: in natural range 0 to 15);
end entity;
-----------------------------------------------
architecture test of test is 
  signal x_d: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  type inp_concat_array is array (0 to 15) of 
    std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); 
  signal inp_concat: inp_concat_array;
begin

  process (clk, reset)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then 
      if reset = '1' then
        x_d <= (others => '0');  
      else 
        x_d <= x; 
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  gen: for i in 0 to 15 generate
    inp_concat(i) <= x(i) & x_d(i);
  end generate;

  test <= inp_concat(test_index);

end architecture;
-----------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your asynchronous for loop is not inside a process, and needs to be: This should do it

```
process(x,x_d)
begin
   for j in 0 to 15 loop
      inp_process(j) <= x(j) & x_d(j);
   end loop;
end process;
```